# Swap and Root: same partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, root, swap

I have 3 partitions, and I can't delete any of them. (Recovery, SYSTEM, C:), and I need to install GNU/Linux.

How can I have swap and root on the same partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can use a swap file instead of mounting swap on a separate partition. This way you can dynamically size the swap file as you see fit without the hassle of partitioning.
2. Create an extended partition so that you can create additional logical partitions for your root, swap, etc.
3. If you don't use hibernation, you may install Linux without using swap at all provided you have sufficient memory space.

Comment: Another option could be another disk.

Comment: Also, many new computers (including the vast majority that ship with Windows 8 and some that shipped with Windows 7, especially in 2012) use the [GUID Partition Table (GPT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioning scheme, which is not limited to four primary partitions. On such a computer, you needn't be concerned with extended/logical partitions or 4-partition limits; you can create as many partitions as you like for all your OSes (up to 128, normally, but even that limit can be raised, if necessary).